# Loading bean definitions from xml after creating ClassPathXmlApplicationContext object

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading, applicationcontext, spring-ioc

I was practicing to use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. One question that strike me is that, is there any way to load the bean definitions from xml after creating the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext object. I am trying something like

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
context.*someMethod*("beans.xml"); // should load bean definitions from beans.xml
```

Is there any method or some approach to do this or this is not possible with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

I know we can use:

```
GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context).loadBeanDefinitions("beans.xml");
context.refresh();
```

But I want to use ClassPathXmlAppllicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it while creating `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` object as follows

```
ApplicationContext context 
  = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.
Yes, I can do it while creating the object of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext but I am trying to figure out is there any way to load the beans.xml after the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext object has been created.